# Is this illegal to watch pornographic videos through the internet in UAE?

Tags: legal

After seeing a news in gulf news I'm asking all of you if you have any suggestions or experience then please share it.
A my friend was saying about this there for want to know in detail.

To watch porn videos it will be cause your arrest in UAE ?

Have you seen or heard about this?

Comment: It heavily depends where one is watching it. On a public street? In a family restaurant? In your hotel room?

Comment: @GeorgeY. No, it doesn't depend at all! whilst it is potentially "more" illegal to watch it on a public street, and you are certainly more likely to be caught doing it there, it doesn't fundamentally change the fact that it is illegal no matter where you watch it.

Comment: He asked whether this will **cause your arrest**, and I don't see any way how watching porn videos in your private hotel room could cause your arrest?

Comment: @GeorgeY. you don't think that home internet use is completely private, do you?

Comment: @RobertColumbia the question asked whether you can get arrested for this, not whether you think it is private or not.

Answer (score 9):

Under UAE law it is illegal to posses or view pornography.  This covers any form of pornography, including Playboy magazines, pornography DVDs and Internet porn.

Most pornographic websites are blocked in the UAE (or so I'm told!), and whilst it may be possible to access them using something like a VPN, this breaks further laws around the use of a VPN or similar technology to circumvent the countries Internet filtering.

Viewing pornography whilst in the UAE can result in a fine of up to 1 million Dirham (around $300K USD) and up to 6 months prison.

Comment: The answer is legally correct, but practically speaking, enforcement is non-existent and the blocking is patchy at best.  The riot squad is not going to burst into your hotel room if you browse to some random porn site.

Comment: I second @jpatokal, I have watched hundreds of hours of porn in the UAE. As long as it's between you, the screen and the dude down there, then no one cares..

Comment: @NeanDerThal 

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the other answer, it is indeed illegal. I would then address the second question, "to watch porn videos it will be cause your arrest in UAE ?" There is difference as enforcement of certain illegal activities in UAE doesn't seem to happen. For example sex outside marriage is illegal in UAE, but lots of visitors practice it without consequences. A quick google search didn't find any single case of someone actually being arrested for watching porn in UAE, so the enforcement seem to be equally weak.

Practically, watching them in privacy, such as your hotel room, despite being illegal, should be safe. Unless your room is wired for video recording, it would be a challenge to prove that (a) **you** (b) **watched** porn. And there is no obvious incentive to do so.

However watching them in a public place, or using your employer's Internet access for this (if you work in UAE) can indeed lead to arrest.

Comment: "it would be a challenge to prove that (a) you (b) watched porn" Internet connection records that show that your device was connected to a port site and was downloading video content?

Comment: The fact that your internet device downloaded porn from a website by itself does not prove that a) it was watched at all, and b) you were the one watching it.