# Is it illegal to watch violent films on an airplane?

Tags: air-travel, legal, etiquette, entertainment

I have a peculiar interest in films and TV shows and understand the content can be seen as strange by others. I'm wondering if I would be break any laws by watch a film on a hijacking (i.e. Captain Philips) on a flight.

Comment: Don’t have any authoritative answer on the topic, but my guess is that it’s not so much you watching it which could be the issue, but who can see it (especially children). You should probably not watch movies with an 18 rating (whatever the name is in your country), but that movie is PG-13, so unless you have a child under 13 right next to you it shouldn’t be an issue. An added precaution could be to use a film on your screen which prevents people from seeing it from an angle.

Comment: I watched Captain Philips on a plane, so I'm pretty sure the answer is "no".   That said, the cabin crew can and will intervene if you're watching Cannibal Holocaust on your own laptop while seated next to preschoolers.

Comment: @lambshaanxy What about watching United 93?

Comment: @EricHernandez I doubt that it is illegal to watch any commercially released film on a flight.  However that doesn't stop fellow passengers and crew objecting to what you are watching - which could lead to all sorts of consequences if you don't follow a crew members orders.  The type of material you are watching will play into how likely someone will complain, and these days it seems that people are more likely to complain about anything.

Comment: Also: What jurisdiction and what origin of film?  What is deemed legal in one country's airline and film industry may be deemed illegal in another one. (EG References to Winnie the Pooh in China or gay kissing in Arab nations will get a different reaction to watching the same subjects in say NZ on a NZ Airlines flight).  Because of this I think that this question is currently unanswerable because it is too broad, and should be closed.

Comment: I've seen horror/violent movies on the inflight entertainment systems.

Comment: What does it matter whether or not it's actually *illegal*? The bar for what may or may not be allowed while on board a privately owned and operated aircraft is set by the owners/operators of the aircraft. If you choose to view something which other passengers find objectionable then the crew may ask you to stop. Failure to obey the crew *is* illegal.

Comment: The question of whether it's illegal will depend on where you're flying (and in the air the legal situation isn't necessarily simple unless you're always within one jurisdiction) so it's impossible to give a simple answer. There's also the issue that many countries have laws about creating a disturbance on an airplane, interfering with the safety of an airplane, etc, which might apply depending on circumstances.

Comment: @Max it's a long time since I've travelled long haul, but some of the more violent action movies that were shown on the seat-back systems tended to be cut, sometimes quite heavily

Answer (score 5):

It's not usually illegal, but you should still be considerate of those around you. Some may not want to see nudity/violence/etc on a plane.  Some of the inflight systems have some of the worst scenes removed(!).

However, I've seen people watching full on pornography in the aisle seat, fully visible to others. Some just have no sense.

One point to consider is the laws of the country your airline is in, especially if flying domestically. If say the movie is banned in that country, you may want to avoid watching, and similarly with [pornographic movies](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/129621/101) or just movies with nudity.